# How to loop multiple objects in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

Look at the last echo line and you will understand my question. I am so new to OOP and don't know how to ask this properly.

```
class myObject {
   function myObject ($obj1var, $obj2var){
      $this->obj1var= $obj1var;
      $this->obj2var= $obj2var;
   }
}

$obj1 = new myObject ("value1","value2");
$obj2 = new myObject ("value1","value2");

for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++){ 
   echo  ${'obj' . $i}->obj1var."&nbsp;"; //this works
   echo ${'obj' . $i}->obj.$i.var."&nbsp;"; //this normally doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Interesting but how people expect me to find older releated subjects without knowing the OOP well.

Comment: Learning how to best use PHP and StackOverflow is a journey.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how you do that:

```
for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++){ 
   echo  ${'obj' . $i}->obj1var."&nbsp;"; //this works
   echo ${'obj' . $i}->{'obj'.$i.'var'}."&nbsp;"; //variable variable
}
```

It is called a [variable property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

You are already using variable variables, this is very similar.